# Android Studio: Fold all methods non-recursively

Tags: android-studio, ide, folding

In Android Studio 3.6.1. (Java 8) there are multiple options for folding (`Code -> Folding`):

- `Collapse` - Collapses the code block the cursor is in, if I put it at the start of a method, it only collapses that but not the `if`, `for`, whatever else inside.
- `Collapse Recursively` - Collapses the code block the cursor is in but also all the `if`, `for`, `//`... inside.
- `Collapse All` - Works like `Collapse Recursively` but collapses all the functions in the file, so it's actually a "Collapse All Rescursively".

Using the third option in a file with a lot of methods/code blocks, if I just want to work on a single method, means that I have to unfold everything inside that code block again.

I know that Eclipse and Visual Studio are able to fold all methods non-recursively (my shortcuts there are: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad /</kbd> for folding and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Numpad *</kbd> for unfolding) but how do I do the same thing in Android Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it appears this can't be done. The best way to deal with this that I've found is to expand the desired method recursively with ctrl alt +